# Write a PL/SQL block which will populate the RESULTS table as described below:

Tags: database, oracle, performance, plsql

I need to insert into the RESULTS table each customer id, and the number of
unique products purchased by that customer. Secondly, I need to update the recently_purchased column of the customer table to 'Y'(yes if they have purchased a product in the last 12 months) or 'N' (if they have not purchased a product in the last 12 months).

Listed below are the tables & definitions:

```
table: CUSTOMER
columns: customer_id NUMBER, customer_name VARCHAR2(100), recently_purchased VARCHAR2(1) -- 'Y' or 'N'

table: CUST_PRODUCTS
columns: product_id NUMBER, customer_id NUMBER, date_purchased DATE

table: RESULTS
columns: customer_id NUMBER, product_count NUMBER

table: PRODUCTS
column: product_id NUMBER, product_name VARCHAR2(100)
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
DECLARE

GET_DATE DATE;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO RESULTS (customer_id, product_count)
SELECT c.customer_id, (select count(product_id) 
                    from CUST_PRODUCTS p 
                    where p.customer_id = c.customer_id)
FROM CUST_PRODUCTS c);

SELECT  date_purchased 
INTO  GET_DATE
FROM CUST_PRODUCTS;
IF GET_DATE < SYSDATE - 365
    UPDATE customer
    SET recently_purchased =  "Y";
ELSE 
    UPDATE customer
    SET recently_purchased =  "N";
END IF;  
END
```

Please help verify this. I do not have any DB software to test my code. Thanks

Comment: You could verify it on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I tried. I receive ORA-00922: missing or invalid option.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon to terminate the `select` right before the `if` statement. Also missing the `end;` to terminate the `declare` block. Also missing semicolons to terminate both `update` statements. Why do you have `customer_id > 0`? Are you expecting non-positive or null customer IDs? Your problem statement is also incomplete: should the `results` table also contain customers who have not purchased any products yet?

Comment: I suggest you to download and install oracle DB (e.g. 11g EE)  from oracle.com, it is free for development-training purposes . Otherwise it's weird to develop and debug code without compiling it . (Besides things mentioned by @Vadim K. there is odd number of brackets in first statement)

Comment: @VadimK. I made the changes you suggested. Still not validating on sqlfiddle.com. Please have a look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9326f/7

Comment: @Mina I don't have download rights on my workstation. Hence, asking for someone to verify for me.

Comment: Here is your sqlfiddle which at least compiles http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9326f/30 , so now you can put some data in it and debug it by yourself ( I would suggest you to query max date purchased for each customer, and not to update all rows but those for particular customer, also in first query where you are counting cust products you would rather join on customer table, etc.)

Comment: You still have not answered the question of whether customers who have not made any purchases should be included in the results table.

Comment: Thanks @Mina. Appreciate that.

Comment: Hi @VadimK. only the customers who have made purchases should appear in the RESULTS table.

Comment: Here is my final solution, for anyone that is interested: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e050/6

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE
        GET_DATE DATE;
        GET_ID Number;  

    CURSOR c1
       IS
         SELECT date_purchased, customer_id
         FROM CUST_PRODUCTS
         WHERE date_purchased < SYSDATE;

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO RESULTS (customer_id, product_count)
        SELECT c.customer_id,(SELECT count(DISTINCT P.product_id) 
        FROM CUST_PRODUCTS P
        WHERE P.customer_id = C.customer_id)
        FROM CUSTOMER C;

        OPEN c1;
        LOOP
         FETCH c1 INTO GET_DATE, GET_ID;
         IF GET_DATE > SYSDATE-365 THEN
            UPDATE CUSTOMER
            SET recently_purchased =  'Y'
            WHERE customer_id = GET_ID;
       ELSE
          UPDATE CUSTOMER
            SET recently_purchased =  'N'
            WHERE customer_id = GET_ID;

       END IF;
         EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        END LOOP;   

       CLOSE c1;

    END;
    //
```